# Route parameter does not return the view with CSS and Javascript

Tags: laravel

I actually have a problem loading the css and Javascrip when i use this route for specific user.

```
Route::get('/auth/{user}','UsersController@view');
```

but it works when I want to see all users

```
Route::get('/users','UsersController@show');
```

I even change the code to this

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/jquery.min.js') }}"> </script>
```

Seems I like I miss something and I can't see what exactly

A little help please!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are your files located in the correct folder in the `public` directory?

Comment: It's really, really hard to know what css/js is loaded in your views, just by looking at the routes you've created. How are you loading these files in your view? Maybe you can share the view you're loading in UsersController@view. On a side note and totally off topic, you might want to take a look at resource controllers: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: the directory assets that content all the css and js file for the template is located in the public folder.

    public function view(User $user)
    {
         return view('auth.show', compact('user'));
    }